# JavaScript divide the string into several parts according to a certain rule

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code with js and outputting a string to a variable. I have sampled this variable below.

`var ResultX = "SefaOODQWHCDCHDAJ=SefaNSADJHDDHQKSefaUQEOFQN==";`

I need to separate this string based on what's between two words and add it to an array or list.
Like this:

`var ResultY = ["SefaOODQWHCDCHDAJ=","SefaNSADJHDDHQK","SefaUQEOFQN=="];`

Output:

```
ResultY[0]=SefaOODQWHCDCHDAJ
ResultY[1]=SefaNSADJHDDHQK
ResultY[2]=SefaUQEOFQN==
```

The reason I'm doing this is because the string I have contains a few Base64 format images. I need to separate them properly so I can process them later.

Can you help with this?
Thank you.

I tried several split and replace methods but failed.

Comment: Can you explain the splitting logic a bit more please and why that's your expected output, I'm not following how you go from the input to the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try using a string `match()` approach:

```js
var ResultX = "SefaOODQWHCDCHDAJ=SefaNSADJHDDHQKSefaUQEOFQN==";
var parts = ResultX.match(/Sefa.*?(?=Sefa|$)/g);
console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var ResultY = [s.slice(0,x),s.slice(x,y),s.slice(y)];
```